# onConfigurationChanged doesn't avoid activity restart on orientation change

Tags: java, android, android-layout, rotation, android-activity

I would like, for a camera app, to avoid redrawing the activity on orientation change.
So far I've been using `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

Now I want the icons to rotate according to orientation change.

Well, it should be very straightforward:
Firstly the code line above is deleted.
Then you set in the manifest for the activity:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

Finally, you override onConfigurationChanged in the activity:

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //Do something
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Now, AFAIK, it should fire onConfigurationChanged **instead** restarting the activity (assuming it will be handled in onConfigurationChanged)

In practice, when orientation is changed, onConfigurationChanged is fired, **but** in addition to the unwanted rotation. How to cancel it? What am I missing?

Device: Xiaomi Mi2s
API: 4.1.1

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: In addition I could implement a simple looper in a saparate thread which reads the accelerometer and act accordingly. But it would be an overkill, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the parent from handling the config as follows:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(null);
    //TODO: Do nothing when orientation has changed...
}
```

As you can see all you need to do is pass null to the super method of onConfigurationChanged, so it will actually prevent from going through all the changes you want to avoid.

Regards!

Comment: The method "onConfigurationChanged" has the annotation "NonNull"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

  if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    //Do something
  } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    //Do something
  }
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

if you don't want to recreate activity, use orientation sensor for detecting orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after the traditional methods failed - I decided to implement orientation change routine by myself.

For this, firstly, I've returned `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`  to the manifest.

Then, I've implemented sensor listener call back with some math:

```
private SensorEventListener listener = new SensorEventListener() {
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {
        if (e.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            float x = e.values[0];
            float y = e.values[1];

            //update _angle in rotate()

            if (Math.abs(y) / Math.abs(x) < 1.0)
            {
                if (x<0 && _angle != 270f)
                    rotate(270f);
                else if(x>=0 && _angle != 90f)
                    rotate(90f);
            }
            else
            {
                if (y<0 && _angle != 180f)
                    rotate(180f);
                else if (y>=0 && _angle != 0f)
                    rotate(0f);
            }
        }

    }
            @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

Works like a charm.